# EAM potential files for LAMMPS Ti-5Ta alloy

Tags: lammps

I want to use the EAM potential of Ti-5Ta alloy for a sintering simulation. A Ti nanoparticle with a hexagonal close-packed (HCP) structure and a Ta nanoparticle with a body centered cubic (BCC) structure. But I do not find any files that meet my needs. Can I generate these potential files some how ? can anyone advice me about this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a simple task to generate potential. If literature is there ask author to provide.